# Error message when loading Geopandas package

Tags: python, geopandas, error, importerror, unicodeencodeerror

I downloaded the latest version of Anaconda and installed `Geopandas` through the navigator. When I import the package the following error message is displayed:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte

Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 283, in defenv
    local._env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 76: invalid continuation byte
```

Even with this message, the package seems to work properly and if I run the same cell again, the message disappears.
Any suggestion?

​

Comment: Seems like Fiona is triggering this, which gets downloaded with geopandas.

Comment: @Yogi, should I update Fiona or something like this?

Comment: @Oalvinegro what operating system, anaconda version and geopandas version did you use? In windows 10, conda 4.11.0, fiona 1.8.13.post1 and geopandas 0.9.0 the install and package works okay for me now, but fiona and geopandas can definitely be troublesome to install on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Possible suggestion on Windows could be to install geopandas from conda command line:

1. Install Anaconda or Miniconda normally, and let the installer add the conda installation of Python to your PATH environment variable (@Oalvinegro) should already have this).
2. Open Anaconda Prompt from start menu
3. Run these commands in command line interface:

```
conda create --name geopandas_env
conda activate geopandas_env
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
```

2 March 2022: this worked for Windows 10, Conda 4.11.0 (probably newer conda version should work too), Python 3.10.2, Fiona 1.8.21 and Geopandas 0.10.2.