# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 63: invalid continuation byte

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have the following error message every time I try to open a meteorological data file (loaded from the Copernicus program) using the plugin UMEP in QGIS. How can I fix it? I am a beginner in Python.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 63: invalid continuation byte 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\UMEP\MetdataProcessor\metdata_processor.py", line 213, in import_file
    header = f.readline().split(delim)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 63: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Is there a data link to download to test?

Comment: The same error in a question from yesterday 
 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423768/error-message-when-loading-geopandas-package? but I do not know if it could have a connection.